# bucle infinito con scanner de java

Tags: java, scanner, java-util-scanner

Con el siguiente código de cuando ingresas un valor no entero (como un carácter o cadena) entra en un bucle infinito en lugar de pedirme de nuevo un entero, cuando se ingresa un entero todo funciona bien

```
public void menu(){
        int b = 0; 
        int opcion;

        System.out.print("BIENVENIDO AL MENU");
        while(b == 0){
            System.out.print("\nA continuacion selecciona la opcion: ");
            System.out.print("\n1.-funcion 1\n2.-funcion 2\n 3.-cerrar");
            try {
                opcion = sc.nextInt();
                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1: {funcion1();}
                    break;
                    case 2: {funcion2();}
                    break;
                    case 3: {b = 1;}
                    break;
                    default:{
                        System.out.println("ERROR: no se ingreso un entero en el rango 1-3");
                    }
                }
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: no se ingreso un entero");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Porque usas nextInt(1)? ¿Has probado con nextInt()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el bucle while definido sólo finaliza en el caso de introducir el número 3.

Si quieres que el bucle finalice cuando introduzcas un número distinto a 1, 2 o 3, en el default del switch debes hacer b = 1;

```
default:{
      System.out.println("ERROR: no se ingreso un entero en el rango 1-3");
      b = 1;
}
```

Si quieres que el bucle finalice cuando introduzcas un caracter en el catch de la excepción debes hacer lo mismo:

```
} catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("ERROR: no se ingreso un entero");
     b = 1;
}
```

Recuerda así mismo hacer el close del Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con la respuesta de zur siempre y cuando desees parar el programa ante un input alfanumérico.

Si cuando te entran un caracter o un string quieres dar el mensaje de error pero no parar, sinó volver a preguntar, entonces es cuando me temo que te aparece el problema.

Para comprenderlo, hay que imaginar el buffer del Scanner, donde hacen cola los datos introducidos por teclado. Cuando lo que se entra no es un entero, el sc.nextInt() no corre la posición de lectura. Para solventarlo, la regla es:

***Cuando esperando un entero entra un caracter, entonces antes de volver a intentar leer otro entero hay que limpiar el buffer.***

Es decir, en tu programa, poner un sc.nextLine() despreciando lo quw retorne (que será un carry return line feed) en el catch.

```
} catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
 System.out.println("ERROR: no se ingreso un entero");
 sc.nextLine();
```

}

Otra forma de hacerlo sería creando un new Scanner en cada iteración, cerrándolo también dentro del bucle. Eso también funcionaría. Claro, si lo destruímos y creamos uno nuevo, limpiamos el buffer.

Añadiría además que la variable b deberia ser booleana, y llamarse "fin", puesto que para eso sirven las booleanas. La variable fin se inicializaría a false, la condición del while sería while (!fin) y en el case 3 poner fin = true.

Espero que sirva.